# Technique to decrease XML size

Tags: xml, http, soap

Probably I'm going to ask the question in a weird way, but I'm not familiar with XML in depth.

I wonder, whether there is a way to decrease size of XML document to make it something like:

Original XML

```
<root>
<longelementname xmlns="long namespace path">Text content</longelementname>
<longelementname xmlns="long namespace path">Text content</longelementname>
<!--................. A lot of elements ...................-->
<longelementname xmlns="long namespace path">Text content</longelementname>
</root>
```

Creating shortcut for namespace and referencing elements through it:

```
<root xmlns:x="long namespace path">
<x:longelementname>Text content</x:longelementname>
<x:longelementname>Text content</x:longelementname>
<!--................. A lot of elements ...................-->
<x:longelementname>Text content</x:longelementname>
</root>
```

Can I create shortcut "s" for "<x:longelementname>" to make it something like:

```
<root>
<s>TextContent</s>
<s>TextContent</s>
<!--................. A lot of elements ...................-->
<s>TextContent</s>
</root>
```

Comment: No, you can't. It will break the xml file if it is going to be checked by it's schema definition. Why do you want to decrease the size?

Comment: I want to send it over the network, and receiving side has limitation on a character number. So I need to send as much elements as possible. So question in general is what techniques can help me to decrease XML size but leaving its meaning intact.

Comment: The usual way is to compress (gzip) the xml, then you also reduce the size of the coontent...  Or just use <s> and tell the receipient to treat s like longelementname in all his further applications. (I don't think it is possible, so that won't help: but you could look at entity definitions)